# Verificar campos de estado de cuenta - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando crear una consulta que me traiga la cantidad de cuentas que tiene un cliente mas cuantas tiene activas y canceladas

Este es el query que tengo

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 c.ClientId
,c.FullnameLocal AS 'Nombre'
,g.cuentas AS 'CuentasAsociadas'

INTO #Temporal1
FROM dbo.Clients AS c

OUTER APPLY(
SELECT 
COUNT(ccr.ContractNumber) AS 'cuentas', co.ContractStatusId
FROM dbo.CustomerContractRelations ccr 
INNER JOIN dbo.Cls_CustomerContractRelationTypes ccrt ON ccrt.CustomerContractRelationTypeId = ccr.CustomerContractRelationTypeId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Contracts co ON co.ContractNumber = ccr.ContractNumber 
WHERE ccr.ClientId = c.ClientId AND ccr.CustomerContractRelationTypeId=1 
) g


SELECT t1.ClientId, t1.Nombre, t1.CuentasAsociadas

FROM #Temporal1  AS t1

DROP TABLE #Temporal1
```

La cosa es que no se como hacer para mostrar los últimos 2 campos que requiero, ya que necesito me aparezca de esta forma por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siendo los estados

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba intentando crear tablas temporales, pero en algunos casos me los separaba el campo de CuentasAsociadas, ya que si un cliente tiene 2 cuentas. una cancelada y otra activa me creaba 2 registros y no deberia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo que muestras en tu código, no es necesario que insertes los datos en una tabla temporal para después mostrarlos. Tampoco es necesario usar `APPLY` puesto que estás cruzando los datos con una tabla que no debería de tener datos repetidos (y por lo mismo tampoco necesitas el `DISTINCT`).

Lo que necesitas es aprender que dentro de una función de agregado va una expresión y no necesariamente una columna. Eso nos permite tener algo que llamo "agregados condicionales".

```
SELECT 
     c.ClientId
    ,c.FullnameLocal AS Nombre
    ,COUNT( ccr.ContractNumber) AS CuentasAsociadas
    ,COUNT( CASE WHEN co.ContractStatusId IN (1,2)   THEN 1 END) AS CuentasActivas
    ,COUNT( CASE WHEN co.ContractStatusId IN (3,4,5) THEN 1 END) AS CuentasCanceladas
FROM       dbo.Clients                           AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerContractRelations         AS ccr  ON ccr.ClientId = c.ClientId
INNER JOIN dbo.Cls_CustomerContractRelationTypes AS ccrt ON ccrt.CustomerContractRelationTypeId = ccr.CustomerContractRelationTypeId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Contracts                         AS co   ON co.ContractNumber = ccr.ContractNumber 
WHERE ccr.CustomerContractRelationTypeId=1 
GROUP BY c.ClientId
        ,c.FullnameLocal;
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya lo probe y funciono perfectamente como queria